# How to put JSON in to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, nsmutablearray

Hi Im new to iOS development and currently got an issue when I develop a scheduling event

Please let me know how to add JSON data instead of the hardcoded array.I need to replace only the customer_name, customer_id from json to this hardcoded data

This is my schedule button click event:

```
- (IBAction)schedule:(id)sender {

    FFCalendarViewController *rootController = [FFCalendarViewController new];
    [rootController setArrayWithEvents:[self arrayWithEvents]];


      [self.navigationController pushViewController:rootController animated:YES];


}
```

this is my hardcoded array:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)arrayWithEvents {

    FFEvent *event1 = [FFEvent new];
    [event1 setStringCustomerName: @"Customer A"];
    [event1 setNumCustomerID:@1];
    [event1 setDateDay:[NSDate dateWithYear:[NSDate componentsOfCurrentDate].year month:[NSDate componentsOfCurrentDate].month day:[NSDate componentsOfCurrentDate].day]];
    [event1 setDateTimeBegin:[NSDate dateWithHour:10 min:00]];
    [event1 setDateTimeEnd:[NSDate dateWithHour:15 min:13]];


    FFEvent *event2 = [FFEvent new];
    [event2 setStringCustomerName: @"Customer B"];
    [event2 setNumCustomerID:@2];
    [event2 setDateDay:[NSDate dateWithYear:[NSDate componentsOfCurrentDate].year month:[NSDate componentsOfCurrentDate].month day:[NSDate componentsOfCurrentDate].day]];
    [event2 setDateTimeBegin:[NSDate dateWithHour:9 min:15]];
    [event2 setDateTimeEnd:[NSDate dateWithHour:12 min:138]];

   return [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[event1, event2]]; 

}
```

This is my json output which i want to replace to the hardcoded array:

```
[  
   {  
      "customer_id":"802",
      "customer_name":"Tela"

   },
   {  
      "customer_id":"803",
      "customer_name":"Bena"
   }
]
```

This is my serialised JSON code:

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSMutableArray  *testFeeds = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

     NSMutableArray   *rec = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [rec addObjectsFromArray:testFeeds];
```

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Do u want to fetch value from json and then replace in ur hardcoded array contents?? m unable to understand

Comment: Yes i have fetched the values and that was the output which i have posted, You are right, need to replace in my hardcoded array contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialise your `json` with below code

```
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

Now `jsonArray` contains mutable data of your `json` file. So you can directly make change or update the values here in this array.

> edit

```
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

NSMutableArray   *rec = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i< jsonArray.count; i++) {
    FFEvent *event1 = [FFEvent new];
    [event1 setStringCustomerName:jsonArray[i][@"customer_name"]];
    [event1 setNumCustomerID:[jsonArray[i][@"customer_id"] integerValue]];
    [event1 setDateDay:[NSDate dateWithYear:[NSDate componentsOfCurrentDate].year month:[NSDate componentsOfCurrentDate].month day:[NSDate componentsOfCurrentDate].day]];
    [event1 setDateTimeBegin:[NSDate dateWithHour:10 min:00]];
    [event1 setDateTimeEnd:[NSDate dateWithHour:15 min:13]];

    [rec addObject:event1];
}
```

Comment: I have Serialised too, i need to know how to apply that ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have edited the question and inserted the coding  for serialisation, please have a look

Comment: @Tela Ok now what is the issue? and what does  **hardcoded array** means??

Comment: Somehow I want to pass a particular value 'customer_name' from this json to where 'Customer A' is in my above code

Comment: @Tela I didn't get you.

Comment: Instead of "Customer A", "Customer B" (Which is in the code) I need pass "Tela", "Bena" which is from the json output